# How to extract value from List[Map[String,String]]?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have this data:

```
val data = List(Map(event_id -> ABC, event_name -> visited, timestamp -> 1478187513, member_id -> 111, category -> web, field1 -> abc), 
     Map(event_id -> DEF, event_name -> added, timestamp -> 1478187520, member_id -> 111),
     Map(event_id -> ABC, event_name -> visited, timestamp -> 1478187522, member_id -> 111, category -> web, field1 -> abc),
     Map(event_id -> ABC, event_name -> visited, timestamp -> 1478187618, member_id -> 111, category -> web, field1 -> abc))
```

How can I extract `member_id` and `field1` from it? The problem is that `member_id` is present in all entries, while `field1` - not.

I tried this, but it does not compile saying `Type mismatch: expected String, actual Int`:

```
val member_id = data.flatMap(_.lift(0)).getOrElse("member_id", "")
```

Comment: What do you want to do if `field1` is not present? Is the return type `Seq[(String,Option[String])]` what you want?

Comment: @mdm: No, I need two String values as a return: `member_id` and `field1` that can be an empty String ("") if there is no `field1`.

Comment: but you can have multiple entries with `member_id`, right? It's a `List[Map[]]`.

Comment: @mdm; Yes, but they are duplicates. I mean that there is the same `member_id` in each Map. The same refers to `field1`. I just want to get the non-empty value for `field1` if there is at least one Map in the List that contains `field1`.

Comment: And is that true for `field1` as well? Are they all going to be duplicates?

Comment: @mdm: I was thinking about something like `data.flatMap(_.lift("member_id")).headOption.get`, but it won't work for `field1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work:

```
data.collect{
  case map if map.keySet.contains(field1) => (map(member_id),map(field1))
}.headOption
```

It will return an `Option[(String, String)]`. I am assuming that 1) there is always a `member_id`, that `member_id` are all the same and that you only care about the first one with a `field1`. If that's not the case, this will throw exceptions.

Additionally, if you are sure that you will have at least one entry that will match your criteria, you can also extract the fields directly:

```
val (memberId, fieldOne) = data.collect{
    case map if map.keySet.contains(field1) => (map(member_id),map(field1))
}.head
```

Again, should there be no value matching the criteria in the initial collection, `head` will throw an exception.

**Edit to respond to latest comment**:

```
val (memberId, fieldOne) = data.collect{
  case map if map.keySet.contains(field1) => (map(member_id),map(field1))
}.headOption.getOrElse((data.head(member_id),""))
```

This will return `fieldOne=""`, with `memberId` set to the correct value, assuming there is at least one entry in the initial `List`. This is very brittle though.

Comment: Is it possible to separately get `val member_id = ...` and `val field1 = `?

Comment: edited to add the extraction. Is this what you needed? I am not sure I understood the question

Comment: This is almost what I need. Thanks. But is it possible just to return `field1=""` in case there is no `field1`, instead of throwing the exception? The rest is absolutely correct and fits my question.

Comment: For instance, is it possible to avoid throwing an exception by adding `.getOrElse("field1", "").get` into your solution in some way? This will give "" if there is no `field1`.

Comment: Probably it should be `case map if map.keySet.contains(field1) => (map(member_id),map(field1)) else map(member_id),""`, right?

Comment: Am I right that there is a typo? Should it be `headOption.getOrElse((data.head(member_id),""))` or `headOption.getOrElse((data.head(field1),""))`?

Comment: I edited my response. The code you put in the last comment would not work, because there is no ordering in what a `Map` returns and we are using `head`: that means that you might get a `fieldOne=""` even if there was a non-empty one.

Comment: The code I posted is correct, because we are returning a Tuple. the first element is memeberId, the second fieldOne